# Extendible X86-64 Assembler

Tags: x86, x86-64, assembly

I'm working on a project whereby we are proposing architectural extensions to x86/x86-64. We have the assembly instructions defined now and up to this point we have been hardcoding them into our C files using statements like asm(".byte 0x04"); The problem here is that this can be tedious and error prone.

I am looking for an existing x86-64 assembler where I can easily define new instructions. I have looked at GAS but I found it a bit difficult to work with. It was designed to be fast, not extensible. Are there any alternatives somebody can suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: What is going to execute these new instructions?

Comment: Extensible assembler should be something controversial...)

Comment: Hello, we will be running our binaries on an architectural simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Any macro assembler such as [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) should be capable of what you seek.

If you want to support your instructions "natively", you'll probably need to obtain the source code for some assembler and modify its code generator.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to what might be the easiest open source assembler to modify?

Comment: No, I have no experience in writing or modifying assemblers. You would probably get excellent help from the FASM community though if you asked at the forum.

Answer (score 2):

MASM and JWASM can back-patch instructions. Write an instruction with the same structure and prefixes as the one you want to generate, then back-patch to replace part of the code.
E.g.

L1: bsf eax, ebx
L2:
org L1+1
db 0BDH           ; replace second byte of instruction
org L2            ; go back to the end of the instruction

This will change the bsf instruction to the bsr instruction with the same operands. However, you must know the size of all prefix bytes in order to put the patch at the right place.

This method has historically been used in macros for new instructions not yet supported by the assembler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like your optimisation documents by the way!